# Check whether particular name order is available in my table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table `stops` how can I check whether the following stops name order `GHI, JKL, MNO` is available in my stops table?

**stops table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops
(
  stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
  lat double(10,6), 
  longi double(10,6)
);
```

**Simple:**

```
1 ABC
2 DEF
3 GHI
4 JKL
5 MNO
6 PQR
7 SDU
8 VWX
```

Comment: where name in ('GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO')?

Comment: with your query I getting six `1` since I have the order `GHI, JKL, MNO` and `MNO, JKL, GHI`

Comment: Is the stop_id always increased by one for the searched group of steps (3,4,5)? No deleted rows?

Comment: @dnoeth: Yes it is always increased by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return `1` when there is an ordered of `'GHI','JKL','MNO'`:

```
SELECT 1
FROM stops s1 
JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1
JOIN stops s3 ON s2.stop_id = s3.stop_id - 1
WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name) = CONCAT('GHI','JKL','MNO')
```

<kbd>[`SQL Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/040e2/5)</kbd>

Comment: `s1.name = 'GHI' and s2.name = ...` will be more index friendly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the well known "find equal sets" task.

You need to insert the searched route into a table with a sequenced `stop_id`:

```
create table my_stops(stop_id INT NOT NULL,
                      name varchar(30) NOT NULL);

insert into my_stops (stop_id, name) 
values (1, 'GHI'),(2, 'JKL'),(3, 'MNO');
```

Then you join and calculate the difference between both sequences. This returns a totally meaningless number, but always the same for consecutive values:

```
select s.*, s.stop_id - ms.stop_id
from stops as s join my_stops as ms
on s.name = ms.name
order by s.stop_id;
```

Now group by that meaningless number and search for a count equal to the number of searched steps:

```
select min(s.stop_id), max(s.stop_id)
from stops as s join my_stops as ms
on s.name = ms.name
group by s.stop_id - ms.stop_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from my_stops)
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4b0a/5)

Comment: Another alternative is `having max(s.stop_id) - min(s.stop_id) = 2`, but using count is more flexible since it allows for more stops in my_stops.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
select 1 
from stops x 
where x.name = 'GHI' 
  and (select GROUP_CONCAT(name order by y.stop_id) 
       from stops y where y.stop_id between x.stop_id + 1 
                                        and x.stop_id + 2
      ) = 'JKL,MNO';
```